# Pulumi get kubernetes context at runtime

Tags: typescript, kubernetes, pulumi

Is there a way to get the current kubernetes context at runtime to prevent calling `pulumi up` with the incorrect context? I'd specifically like to make sure my local kubernetes deployment logic doesn't end up in anything other than a local cluster.

I've gone through the examples and don't see anything that does this: https://github.com/pulumi/examples/search?l=TypeScript&p=2&q=context&type= (maybe I'm thinking about my problem the wrong way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [here](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/cloud-providers/kubernetes/setup/), first you have to create a context for your cluster that will be used, for example:

```
kubectl config \
    set-context <my-context> \
    --cluster=<my-cluster> \
    --user=<my-user>
```

Then run `pulumi stack init new-kube-stack` where you will be asked to enter your access token and finally run `pulumi config set kubernetes:context my-context` to work in a cluster defined in previously created context.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit**
You can set the kubeconfig dynamically using the kubeProvider

```js
// Define k8sProvider based on the stack
let k8sProvider: k8s.Provider;

if (stackName === "local") {
  const kubeConfigPath = path.join(os.homedir(), ".kube", "config"); // Path to the kubeconfig file assuming ~/.kube/config
  const kubeconfig = fs.readFileSync(kubeConfigPath, 'utf8');
  k8sProvider = new k8s.Provider("k8sProvider", {
    kubeconfig: kubeconfig
  });
} else {
  const label = "cluster-label";
  const lkePool: linode.types.input.LkeClusterPool[] = [{ type: "g6-standard-4", count: 2, autoscaler: { min: 2, max: 6 } }]
  const lkeCluster = new linode.LkeCluster("cluster-label", { label: label, pools: lkePool, region: "us-ord", k8sVersion: "1.29" })
  const kubeconfig = lkeCluster.id.apply(async (id) => {
    const cluster = await linode.getLkeCluster({ id: Number(id) });
    return Buffer.from(cluster.kubeconfig, "base64").toString();
  });

  k8sProvider = new k8s.Provider("k8sProvider", {
    kubeconfig: kubeconfig
  });
}
```

This way you can pass the k8sProvider to your Kubernetes objects like this `{ provider: k8sProvider }`:

```js
const dockerSecret = new k8s.core.v1.Secret("regcred", {
  metadata: { name: "regcred" },
  type: "kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson",
  data: {".dockerconfigjson": Buffer.from(dockerConfigJson, 'utf8').toString('base64'),
  }
}, { provider: k8sProvider });
```

---

I had a similar problem. I manage different Kubernetes clusters and wanted to be certain to apply pulumi to the corrent context.

```js
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import * as child_process from "child_process";
import { promisify } from "util";

const exec = promisify(child_process.exec);

async function getCurrentKubectlContext() {
  try {
    // Using kubectl to get the current context
    const { stdout, stderr } = await exec("kubectl config current-context");
    if (stderr) {
      console.error("Error fetching current kubectl context:", stderr);
      return null;
    }
    return stdout.trim();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to fetch current kubectl context:", error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

It runs `kubectl config current-context` which gives you the context kubectl is working on.

Then in my `index.ts` I execute it like this:

```js
// Fetch and log the current Kubernetes context
getCurrentKubectlContext().then(context => {
  if (context) {
    // console.log(`Current Kubernetes context : ${context }`);
    pulumi.log.info(`Current Kubernetes context : ${context}`);
  }
}).catch(error => {
  console.error("Failed to fetch current kubectl context:", error);
});
```

Then when running `pulumi up` before selecting `yes` or `no` it prints out your current context.

[image: pulumi outputs current Kubernetes context]